# How to do the same controller action to create an image for one button but not for another?

Tags: magento-1.8, module, controllers

We are calling same controller action for 2 buttons for create product pro-grammatically and assign a custom image for that product.

**1. create - custom image  uploading for newly created product**

**2. login - custom image not uploading for newly created product**

**Create:**

```
<button  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();" id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" title="{{apply_text}}">{{apply_text}}</button>

initObservers: function() { 
    if (this.config.editorEnabled) {  
        $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.saveDesignBut.bindAsEventListener(this)); 
    } 
},
```

**Login code:**

```
$params = array(
    '_secure' => (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'),
    'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()
);

<form id="ajaxlogin-login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', $params) ?>">

<button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
```

**Controller code:**

```
$images = array(
    'thumbnail' => 'image.png', // displaying under cart 
    //'small_image' => 'image.png',
    'image' => 'image.png' // displaying under my design
);

foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
    if ($newImagePath != "") {
        $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
        $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
    } else {
        $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
        $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
    }
}
```

Please give me some hint for this ...

Comment: Try to put log in controller for check in both button controller is called.

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies yes, in both buttons that controller is called because  new product is creating programtically for both buttons, but only custom image is missing for `login` button......

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies pleas help me for this, i am facing this issue from last 3 months and its completely destroying me mentally every day.....

Comment: Can you give whole controller code, update in question

Comment: in that please these 2 functions : `createSimpleProductAndRedirectAction()` and `_createProduct`

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies here you can see complete `create` button code : http://pasted.co/ec59c4c7 , here login button code : http://pasted.co/73969e45

Comment: Can you put log for: file_exists($path) and $path and check

Comment: please check and tell is this is correct : `Mage::log("File Path: " . $path, Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'debug.log');`   ?

Comment: Yes and in another log put this:file_exists($path)

Comment: i added as `Mage::log("File Path: " . $path, Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'debug.log');
      Mage::log("File Path: " . file_exists($path), Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'debug1.log');`

Comment: Yes check what is in loh

Comment: actually once we click on `login` button image not creating in server, so only its not assignin g to newly created product......